# Is this way to execute procedure is safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

example code from DAL:

I am using c# and SQL SERVER as database.

I wrote singleton of Database object , and example 
function that exceute procedure from mssql,
using DbCommand and Database-AddInParameter

I found topics that talks about parametes and sql injection but 
I want to know about this specific way

```
private Database m_db;
public Database getDB
{
      get
         {
            if(m_db == null)
                  m_db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
            return m_db;
         }
 }


public void Example(string Name)
{
    DbCommand dbcmd = getDB.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.Example");
    getDB.AddInParameter(dbcmd, "p_Name", DbType.String, Name);
    getDB.ExecuteNonQuery(dbcmd);
}
```

thanks

Comment: This is fine from c# side, although it depends how your procedure looks like.

Comment: It totally depends on what kind of commands stored inside the SP. In C# side it is safe to use `AddInParameter`, but in SQL side may be different thing if it contains dynamic query using string concatenation.

Comment: So as long as I don't use string concatenation as query it will be safe from sql injection? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dbo.Example` procedure can definitely still execute a query which is not safe, for example:

```
create proc dbo.Example (@pName varchar(100))
as
    declare @cmd varchar(max);
    set @cmd = 'select Somedata from Sometable where Somecolumn = '+ @pName;
    exec (@cmd);
```

Safe code uses proc parameter in a query exactly as a parameter

```
create proc dbo.Example (@pName varchar(100))
as
   select Somedata from Sometable where Somecolumn = @pName;
```

Comment: Correct, @Or you need to consider both the method used to call the procedure (the C# code you have is safe from this perspective), but also how the stored procedure consumes those variables. Two key principles: parameterize everything and don't ever mix potentially unsafe variables with clean queries.

Comment: 1. What do you mean about "clean queries"?

    2. If I will not execute the procedure above as a string with 'exec(@cmd)' and execute it normaly, it will be safe?
 `create proc dbo.Example (@pName varchar(100)) 
as 
select Somedata
 from Sometable
 where Somecolumn = + @pName`
@pcdev

Comment: 1. Something is considered "dirty" if it is in any way sourced from untrusted input.  This means not only strings entered by a user, but also data loaded from file, database field, or downloaded from a website (these can all be compromised).  If you don't have complete control over the source of the string then it's "dirty" and needs to be very carefully handled.

Comment: 2. Yes, if you're not building and executing sql then there is no risk of injection per se, as per @Serg's edit. If you _really_ need to build dynamic sql, this can still be done safely by parameterizing it again with sp_executesql like this: `exec sp_executesql @cmd, N'@param1 varchar(max)', @param1 = @pname;`

Comment: Finally, [here's](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) an excellent tutorial that covers many common injection targets and how to protect against them, and once you've read that you'll understand [this](https://xkcd.com/327/) (obligatory) xkcd comic which is right on topic here :)